# Meaning of "want a little pressing"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> She only wanted a little pressing to accept it.

Is this sentence alone inferring she wanted to accept it from heart, or is inferring she actually didn't want to accept it, or this sentence alone can be ambiguous?(Or is it completely other meanings that I am totally wrong?)

It sounds like "No one wanted her to accept it, but she from heart wanted to accept it, hence hoping others to force(press) her a little bit, so that she can accept it naturally." to me, is my understanding correct? Otherwise the combination of "only" and "want other's to press her" doesn't fit to me.

Comment: It would help if you provided more context. But anyway... Even though it sounds ambiguous, a sentence such as this one almost never means that someone actually *wants pushing*, i.e., what you described as "from heart" (this sounds unnatural, you need something between these two words). If I'm interpreting it correctly, the sentence implies (not *infers*) that she didn't need much convincing – but that's it – it says nothing more about her. She didn't oppose it vehemently, but she wasn't very eager to accept it, either. I'd describe it as "politely accepting".

Comment: *wanted* there can be understood to mean *needed*.  To accept it, she needed only a little "pressing" or urging or, as userr2684291 puts it, "convincing".  The meaning would be clearer if **only** was placed so that it modified "a little": *She wanted only a little pressing to accept it.* That is the intended meaning. Native speakers (and writers) are often not very precise in their use of the word **only** and rely upon context to make their meaning clear.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: It only means "needed" in the sense that "need" means "lack." It is more precise to say it means "lacked" there.

Comment: @Robusto: not sure I'd agree.  Can we 'lack' something that others do to us? The shirt lacked ironing. She lacked pressing.  ??   But I do agree, that **need** there, in the way I'm using it, means **require**. "I need your driver's license", said the policeman.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: "**want** 6. To be without; lack." (See, really, any dictionary.) This is the sense of it. It's a somewhat archaic use of the term, but that's how literature of the 19th and early 20th century renders it. And it is not "our" lack as seen from "our" perspective, but something or someone's as seen from someone else's. "The painting wanted only a frame to make it worthy of a gallery setting." The painting lacked a frame.

Comment: This is from "Pride and Prejudice". If you read the whole paragraph you will understand this sentence better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speakers and writers are often very "sloppy" in their placement of the word **only**, relying upon context to disambiguate.

You haven't given us much context, but the intended meaning there is almost surely this:

> She needed only a little pressing to accept it.

With a different verb complement, the placement of **only** could lead to considerable ambiguity. For example:

> She only wanted to buy the car.

That could mean:

*She alone wanted to buy the car. Perhaps her husband and children wanted a different kind of car.*

or

*She didn't want to lease the car. She wanted to purchase it.* or perhaps that buying that car was the only thing on her mind at that moment, she desired it very much.

To clear up some of that ambiguity we could write:

> Only she wanted to buy the car.
>
> She wanted only to buy the car.